# plsql update statement

Tags: plsql

I want to write a update procedure

Which of the method is best

1) **Method 1**

```
if(condition)="P"

update table 
set fields1
 where field2 = "2" ;


else(condition)="U"
update table
 set fields1
 where field3 = "3" ;
```

**2) Method 2**

```
 case condition
   when "p"
update table 
set fields1
 where field2 = "2" ;


   when "u"
   update table
 set fields1
 where field3 = "3" ;
```

which method should i use  is there a reason to use it  and why the other is not a good option.

Answer (score 2):

```
update table t
  set ...
  where (condition='P' and field2='2') or (condition='U' and field3='3')
```

Comment: HI.. wont this query takes more time,if the table is huge?? because for Each row it has to check those conditions..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use **CASE** , because **CASE** is more efficient and readable wen comparing to **IF**. 
But if u have small table and only 2 cases to check.. It doesnt make any sense i think..